# Thin Black lines on start up?

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, startup-file, screencast

[image]Okay, so I have this triangle looking thing, made of a thin black line on every startup file. I have made a few different startup files to try to fix it, but it shows up on every one. Any info?

Comment: Most likely an issue with the drivers for the GPU. Update, re-install or downgrade and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: If there is only one object in the scene which is called Plane (seems from Outliner that it is) then indeed this is GPU driver problem.

Comment: Do you have any addons enabled? If I recall correctly there used to be an addon that saved the 3D cursor position history and showed thin lines like those.

Comment: Nvidia did just update, but I did recall enabling the 3D Cursor Control Add-On. I disabled the add-on and this resolved the issue. Thank you guys, for all your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore the factory defaults by clicking: File > Load Factory Settings.[image]

Then press ctrl+U for the default